# Oozie - Spark Action > where to add ojdbc.jar to access oracle JDBC

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, oozie, ojdbc

I am trying to create a Spark Action in Oozie for the below command:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --class com.spark.sql.jdbc.SparkDFtoOracle --jars /home/oracle/ojdbc7.jar --driver-class-path /home/oracle/ojdbc7.jar testOracleJdbcDF.jar > tmp
```

This is giving N number of errors in Oozie. I have used the template of workflow.xml from oozie-examples.tar.gz.

Can anyone please help me to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of adding dependency jars. I'd create a directory named **lib** next to `workflow.xml` in HDFS and place jars(`ojdbc7.jar`) in there. Oozie will automatically make those jars available to all actions in that workflow.

**workflow.xml**

```
<workflow-app name="sample-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
    <action name="myfirstsparkjob">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>[JOB-TRACKER]</job-tracker>
            <name-node>[NAME-NODE]</name-node>
            <prepare>
                <delete path="${jobOutput}"/>
            </prepare>
            <master>yarn</master>
            <mode>client<mode>
            <name>Spark DF to Oracle</name>
            <class>com.spark.sql.jdbc.SparkDFtoOracle</class>
            <jar>hdfs/path/to/testOracleJdbcDF.jar</jar>
            <spark-opts>--driver-class-path path_to-some_other_jar </spark-opts>
        </spark>
        <ok to="myotherjob"/>
        <error to="errorcleanup"/>
    </action>
</workflow-app>
```

[Spark Action Extension in Ozzie](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html)

**About your spark submit:**

In your spark submit `--driver-class-path` is not needed because as the value is same as `--jars`. check `--driver-class-path` description:

> Extra class path entries to pass to the driver. Note that jars added
>   with --jars are automatically included in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Install Ojdbc7.jar in Maven and add the below dependency in POM.xml file

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>oracle.jdbc.driver</groupId>
   <artifactId>oraclethin</artifactId>
   <version>12c</version>
</dependency>
```

Build the jar with dependencies.

Comment: I'd recommend not to go with `fat jar` because of size and time to copy into the cluster. copying unresolved maven jars in ozzie shared location and use it for all spark applications.

Comment: In my case we are using fat jar, installed ojdbc7.jar in local system, added the dependency in pom file. The size of jar is not more than 3 MB. With this we don't need to do any additions in <spark-opts>.